# Make Https in uvicorn VPS to run api deep learning, error 429

Tags: python, ubuntu, vps, uvicorn

When i use this code

```
uvicorn App:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --ssl-keyfile key.pem --ssl-certfile cert.pem --reload
```

i cant access with

```
export const Hate = async (term) => {
  const response = await fetch("https://<IP_ADDRESS>:8000/hate", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: term }),
  });

  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};
```

error 429 when access with fetch

```
app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

How to fix that, when i access with https://<IP_ADDRESS>:8000/hate will be run api deep learning to show prediction on fetch